# Kurento Screen Sharing with ReplayKit iOS Library

Tags: ios, webrtc, live-streaming, kurento

Currently I'm working on Project where we are using Kurento media server for media management, till now everything working fine like we can join in the room and share camera streams.

Now I want to share screen display as streams with the kurento server at my iOS app side.

Anybody know how to tackle this Problem ??